# How do I find details of the current UIView animation?

Tags: uiview, uianimation

I have a setter method for a property on a custom `UIView` class.  If it's set within a `UIView` animation block, I'd like it to add a `CABasicAnimation` to the view's layer with the same duration and easing as the `UIView` animation.  How do I find out whether I'm inside a `UIView` animation block, and **how do I get its duration and easing curve?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this question I made this extension to `UIView` block animations: [UIView+AnimatedProperty](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/UIView-AnimatedProperty).

It allows you to run `CAAnimations` when the setter is called from animation block. Example with `cornerRadius` is included.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple..
You can get all animation keys applied to your view using

```
[self.YourView.layer animationKeys];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current animation easily enough. For instance, setting up a `CATransaction`:

```
CAAnimation *animation = [self.layer animationForKey:self.layer.animationKeys.firstObject];
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:animation.duration];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:animation.timingFunction];

// CALayer animation here

[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [UIView animateWithDuration] states that

> This method performs the specified animations immediately using the UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut and UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animation options.

As for the duration, you set the duration yourself, so you already now that.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the options. I don't necessarily know the duration, as I'm writing a setter for a property that someone else may call either within or without an animation block.  I want to know whether or not I'm inside an animation, and if so what its duration is.

Comment: totally missed that bit :/